# Math related program

Tags: number-theory

Hi I am wondering for a program that can check when the sums of divisors of an odd square number will be equal to the sums of divisors of powers of 2. So when does $$\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(2^k)$$

Comment: just wrote a quick search code. It found `n=5, k=4`. But can't find any more. Is there supposed to be more than this?

Comment: thank you nassar. I am wondering that exact thing too...I believe there could be but maybe quite large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is a quick search code. Tried up to `n=1,000,000` but could only find `n=5, k=4`. It took only 3 minutes on my PC. But may be you can try it over night and see if it can find more.

```
keepSearching = True;
n = 3;
maxToSearch  = 10000;

Last@Reap@While[keepSearching,
   lhs = DivisorSigma[1, n^2];
   Do[
    rhs = DivisorSigma[1, 2^k];
    If[rhs == lhs,
     Print["found n=", n, " k=", k];
     Sow[{n, k}]
     ,
     If[rhs > lhs, Return[]]
     ],
    {k, 1, 10000}
    ];
   n = n + 2;
   If[n > maxToSearch, keepSearching = False]
   ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Do you know you could just use `DivisorSigma[]`?

Comment: @J.M. never heard of DivisorSigma before. But thanks for point it out. Will change the code to use that instead of the explicit way I did.